# How to remove MAT from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I installed MAT in eclipse, but now my eclipse is not starting. How can I remove MAT from Eclipse? (Through file system)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to move the plugin file from `<Eclipse_directory>/dropins`
2. If your plugin is not seen there, try with `<Your_Workspace_Location>/.metadata/.plugins` and then move the MAT plugin outside.
3. Start Eclipse in `clean` mode.

Comment: MAT plugin is not there in either place.